# Get SVN info as CMake variable

Tags: svn, cmake

I try to save SVN log output to CMake variable. What I have right now is:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND "svn info"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE SVN_INFO
)
message("SVN: \"${SVN_INFO}\"")
```

Output:

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:7 (message):
  SVN: ""
```

I know little about CMake, so simple and clear answers are more than welcome. Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that I'm working on Linux.

**Edit 2:**
I'm sure that CMakeLists.txt is in root directory of SVN.

Comment: `I know little about CMake` - So, may be start with tutorial? Correct variable's dereference: `message("SVN: ${SVN_INFO}")`.

Comment: I want to get comment with variable surrounded with quotation mark, so that's correct I guess. Anyway, it does not explain why `SVN_INFO` variable is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't expect that qoutation is intended. Please, next time describe what you need in the question itself... Or better, ask specifically what is uncleared and do not introduce any other difficultes into the code. As for emptiness of `SVN_INFO`, it could be many reasons: `svn` isn't found, it outputs version into stderr, and so on. With `execute_process` you may check stderr and return value of the command.

Comment: `I'm sure that CMakeLists.txt is in root directory of SVN.` - Unrelated to your problem. For execute `svn` without path you need to have svn binary under directory in `PATH`, current directory doesn't affect on searching.

Comment: I don't know why this doesn't work, but the more CMake-like way would be to call `FIND_PACKAGE(Subversion REQUIRED)` first and then use the provided function `Subversion_WC_INFO`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindSubversion.html